# In Orbeon Forms, why is focus set to the first Input Field instead of the first field?

Tags: forms, validation, constraints, orbeon

In Orbeon Forms 4.7, I have a form in which the first two fields are both required. They are:

1. A Dropdown Menu
2. An Input Field

When I run the form in Form Runner, focus is set to the Input Field. In other words, the cursor is in that field. The dropdown is the first field so I select a value from it. Since the Input Field has now lost focus, the validation immediately displays an error because the Input Field is missing a value.

So the validation is telling the user that they did something wrong, when all they did is answer the first question first. This looks bad and seems like incorrect behaviour.

If I can disable this instant validation, this probably won't be an issue for me. I have another question open regarding that:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289498/in-orbeon-forms-is-it-possible-to-disable-instant-validation-but-still-validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point. I thought that on OS X, by default, dropdowns were not focusable, this unless "All controls" was selected in the preferences for "Full Keyboard Access". Thus, Orbeon Forms didn't want to set the focus on a control on which, sometimes, the focus can't be set by the browser. But:

- This might be a bad idea, and the use case you describe supports that.
- The default in OS X is "text boxes *and lists* only" (highlight mine). That doesn't include buttons, but includes dropdowns.

So I think it would be better for Orbeon Forms to include selection controls (in addition to text fields and textareas) in the list of "focusable controls" it considers when setting the focus on the first control. I created [issue #1958](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1958) to cover this.

Comment: Thanks, avernet. Another useful option would be to allow configuring forms so that focus is not set to any field at all. That also would solve this problem since most users are just going to click on the dropdown anyway. In addtion, it would provide a workaround in case another type of unfocusable control is first in the form.

Comment: @awilkinson True; we'll think about it.

Comment: @avernet - As we are using older version of Orbeon, so any quick fix which we can apply to set autofocus on first control (using js/javascript/css).

Comment: @U2Answer I image you could write custom JavaScript to set the focus, in a way "overriding" the control Orbeon Forms sets the focus on. But I can see this quickly becoming tricky, so I'm sure this really is a workaround worth considering.